# The method Distinct is not supported

Tags: entity-framework-4, distinct, wcf-data-services

I am using Linq to Entities and am getting this error

```
The method Distinct is not supported
```

On this line of code

```
var typeIds = _context.AttributeValues.Select(av => av.AttributeTypeId).Distinct();
```

Why is this?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or another database with its own LINQ-to-Entities provider?

Comment: Or is this WCF data services?

Comment: I am using SQL Server and WCF data services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to define a WCF Data Service using (server-side) the `QueryByCube` method provided by my product AdaptiveLINQ ([www.adaptivelinq.com](http://www.adaptivelinq.com)). **This method transforms a projection (expressed by the select operator) in an aggregation**.

You have just to define a cube with one dimension : AttributeTypeId

```
av => av.AttributeTypeId
```

Define a Data Service providing the queryable collection:

```
yourDbContext.AttributeValues.QueryByCube(yourCube);
```

Now you can query your service using the OData protocol:

```
http://.../myService.svc/AttributeValues?$select=AttributeTypeId
```

Or, if your using a C# client:

```
serviceContext.AttributeValues.Select(x => x.AttributeTypeId);
```

The advantage of this solution relative to the workaround proposed A J Qarshi is that **the distinction is made on the server side**.

Comment: I've approved your edit to the question only after checking your answer. For future reference, it's always better if you can provide a useful description as to why the tag is needed and why does it make sense.

Answer (score 1):

As per MSDN few LINQ methods are not supported which using OData service. Below is a partial list of unsupported methods.

- All
- Any
- Concat
- DefaultIfEmpty
- Distinct
- Except
- Intersect
- Union
- Zip

For a full list of unsupported operations see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622463(v=vs.110).aspx)

However, as a workaround following statement should work in this case.

```
var typeIds = _context.AttributeValues
                      .Select(av => av.AttributeTypeId)
                      .AsEnumerable()
                      .Distinct();
```