# OData v4 groupby with $count

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm using OData v4 with WebAPI with these nuget-packages:

[Microsoft.Data.OData 5.7.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.OData/5.7.0)

[Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 4.0.30506](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData/4.0.30506)

I can't get `groupby` to work with count. It should be the most simple thing.

I have a simple table/entity called `Delivery`. It has a status column (among several other ones). What I basically want to do is this SQL query, but with OData:

```
SELECT e.status, count(*) AS total
FROM Delivery e
GROUP BY e.status
```

I've tried using [`countdistinct`](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-data-aggregation-ext/v4.0/cs01/odata-data-aggregation-ext-v4.0-cs01.html#_Standard_Aggregation_Method), but it doesn't give me the correct results.

```
/odata/deliveries?$apply=groupby((status),aggregate(status with countdistinct as total))
```

It returns:

```
"value": [
{
    "@odata.id": null,
    "total": 1,
    "status": 1
},
{
    "@odata.id": null,
    "status": 2,
    "total": 1
},
{
    "@odata.id": null,
    "status": 4,
    "total": 1
}
]
```

The correct results should be (which is what my SQL-query returns):

```
status  total
1       2
2       22
4       1
```

I've also read about the virtual property [`$count`](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-data-aggregation-ext/v4.0/csprd01/odata-data-aggregation-ext-v4.0-csprd01.html#_The_Virtual_Property), but it seems as Microsoft [doesn't support it yet](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/773).

**How do I use `group by` together with a simple `count` with OData v4?**

Comment: It looks like this might not be supported yet: https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/773

Comment: @TomDoesCode, Yes. I have the same link in my question, but I hoped that it could be done some other way.

Comment: Oh yes, I see it now, sorry! (I'm blaming my dodgy screen colours for not spotting the link)

Comment: @TomDoesCode, no probs. :) I appreciate any clues and any help I can get.

Comment: A solution is to use the LINQ extension method `QueryByCube` from the [AdaptiveLINQ](http://www.adaptivelinq.com) component. (Disclaimer: I'm the AdaptiveLINQ developper).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Whilst $count is not supported, contdistinct has been supported for a while and is possibly more syntactically correct for OData aggregate scenarios, the documentation is a little bit lacking but countdistinct gives the caller control over which field to use in the result set to determine the unique results. This is especially useful in complex nested or expanded grouping queries.

So it turns out you have a simple bug in your query!

In your query:
`/odata/deliveries?$apply=groupby((status),aggregate(status with countdistinct as total))`

You are asking for count all the *distinct* values of status. Because you are grouping by status, the distinct values in each group will always be 1 :)

Your actual query should be to countdistinct over a property that will be unique for each item in the set, usually an Id. Assuming Delivery has an Id field called "Id", your query should be this:

```
/odata/deliveries?$apply=groupby((status),aggregate(id with countdistinct as total))
```

this will translate closely to your expected SQL:

```
SELECT status, COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS total
FROM Delivery
GROUP BY status
```

Comment: can any filter or group be applied on the results of odata? Say, I want to select only those who have total as 2. Is it even possible?

Comment: You can `$filter` the group by result by appending your query with `&$filter=total eq 2` but that is less useful, it wont return all the items that satisfy the criteria, only the groups that do.

Answer (score 4):

Currently in ODATA v4, it supports the requirement which you have

```
/Entity/$apply=groupby((status),aggregate($count as COUNT))
```

The above code translates to the following

```
select status, count(*) from  entity group by status;
```

Comment: According to the standard this should work ... but Microsofts implementation is broken and doesn't do this ... STILL! nearly a year after you posted this :(

Comment: @War Adding `.AddODataNewtonsoftJson();` to your AddControllers declaration should fix this:         

            builder.Services.AddControllers()
                .AddNewtonsoftJson()
                .AddOData(options => options.EnableQueryFeatures()
                .AddRouteComponents("api/v{version:apiVersion}/odata", 
                OdataEdmModel.GetEdmModel()))
                .AddODataNewtonsoftJson();