# MS CRM Online: Get all accounts with more than X contacts

Tags: dynamics-crm, odata, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-webapi

Is it possible to get all accounts in MS CRM Online with more than X contacts via odata (this is probably not possible via FetchXML)?

Something like (dummy code, does not work):

```
accounts?$apply=aggregate(contact_customer_accounts with countdistinct as total)/filter(total gt X)
```

Comment: I think the only way to do this would be to add a calculated field to Account that counts the number of Contacts

Comment: Thanks - I actually wanted to avoid this, but I think you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible as it is not straight forward with a single query using fetchxml (no support for subquery and aggregation with having clause) or [web api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/query-data-web-api#aggregate-and-grouping-results). You can pull all the results and do aggregation using LINQ or other ways.

Compared to that, using a single rollup attribute to count the child contact records on parent account (not a calculated field) is the easiest option.

Comment: also, check this answer and comment by chris, give it a try - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45850995/7920473